# How to autofill a column with a single text and making it read only?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

- I need to create an Excel file where the first column of every row should be a fixed text string.
- This column should not be editable.

The reason for this requirement is that the user can save this file as a `csv` file, which can then be used as input for a software. That software requires the first column to be set to a constant text string.

Answer (score 1):

It's a while since I locked a s/sheet for real, but I believe the secret is that all cells are by default locked. This has no effect until the sheet is locked.
So first unlock all cells, then select and lock your first column cells and finally lock the sheet.
The users can now add data to  the unlocked cells.

Not sure exactly what you are expecting the users to do, but you should be able to just allow them access to a few columns, and lock the rest.

Search for "password protect excel cells" and there are tutorials around if you need more detailed instructions.

Comment: After locking the sheet will the users will be able to add more rows?